# Linkedin API - split file chunking not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, linkedin-api

I'm using the video API from LinkedIn to upload a video - but there must be something wrong with my file chunking approach, as I get an error:

```
data: {
  owner: 'urn:li:person:a1b2c3d4e5',
  processingFailureReason: 'CORRUPTED_ENTITY',
  id: 'urn:li:video:V5910dQH83nkpw91Dww',
  status: 'PROCESSING_FAILED'
}
```

My MP4 video file size is `20301174` and apparently the byte chunk size is `4194303` as per the [Linkedin API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/videos-api?view=li-lms-2023-02&tabs=http) - which means that the following code should work:

```
const splitVideo = async (filepath) => {
  
    var blobsArray = []

    const buffer = fs.readFileSync(filepath, {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'})

    const blobParent = new Blob([buffer], {type: 'video/mp4'})

    const blobChild1 = blobParent.slice(0, 4194303, 'video/mp4') // 4194303 bytes
    const blobChild2 = blobParent.slice(4194304, 8388607, 'video/mp4') // 4194303 bytes
    const blobChild3 = blobParent.slice(8388608, 12582911, 'video/mp4') // 4194303 bytes
    const blobChild4 = blobParent.slice(12582912, 16777215, 'video/mp4') // 4194303 bytes
    const blobChild5 = blobParent.slice(16777216, 20301174, 'video/mp4') // 3523957 bytes

    const blobsArray = [blobChild1, blobChild2, blobChild3, blobChild4, blobChild5]

    return blobsArray
}
```

Any tips or guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there's way too many issues with my above code, but I now have a working [example here](https://gist.github.com/spraddles/21980a7c97fda3a0ce1d1c100384def1).

File chunking needs to be via bash `split -b 4194303` I tried so many JavaScript methods to split the file, but none of them were accepted by LinkedIn's API.

Also the uploaded file needs to be sent via `readFileSync` which is synchronous not asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you don't include last byte in every chunk.
According to linkedin documatnion `firstByte` and `lastByte` is **inclusive**.

It's mean you need to split file to `4194304 bytes` **NOT** `4194303 bytes`.

If you want to use `uploadInstructions` you can use this code.

**NOTE**: You must add `+ 1` in different, because both first and last byte are inclusive.

```
byte = instructions.lastByte - instructions.firstByte + 1;
```

Comment: This saved me a huge headache.  Thank you!